# Error: I'm getting an item not found error." chart.render() "

Tags: reactjs, next.js, fetch-api, apexcharts

" I get Error: Element not found error." chart.render() " removes the question mark and it gets fixed, but when I refresh the page after removing it, it still gives the same error, then when I put the question mark it works. It gives window not found error from time to time."

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, FC, useMemo } from"react";
import ApexCharts from 'apexcharts'
import Head from 'next/head'
import styles from '../../../../styles/Home.module.css'
import CurrencyFormat from 'react-currency-format';
import Image from "next/image";


    function App() {
        const [i, setSeti] = useState();
        const [countries, setCountries] = useState();


        useEffect(() => {
            fetch(
                "https://api.reservoir.tools/collections/daily-volumes/v1?id=0xed5af388653567af2f388e6224dc7c4b3241c544&limit=10"
            )
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((response) => setSeti(response));
        }, []);


        const SaleCountt = []
        const Datess = []
        const Floorr = []
        const DailyWorthh = []
        const DailyNetWorthh = []




        var si = i?.collections;



        si?.map(function (item) {
            SaleCountt.push(Math.round(item.sales_count));
            var date = new Date(item.timestamp * 1000).toLocaleDateString("en-US");
            Datess.push(date)
            Floorr.push((item.floor_sell_value).toFixed(1))
            DailyWorthh.push(item.sales_count)
            DailyNetWorthh.push(item.sales_count) 


        })


        const Dates = Datess.reverse();
        const SaleCount = SaleCountt.reverse();


        var options = {
            chart: {
                type: 'bar',
                height: 350

            },
            colors: ["#2E268D"],

            title: {
                text: 'Sale Count',
                align: 'left'
            },
            series: [
                {

                    name: 'sales',
                    data: SaleCount,

                }
            ],
            xaxis: {
                type: 'datetime',

                categories: Dates
            }
        }
```

"The chart.render() here gives an error"

```
    var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector('#chart'), options)
chart.render()

return (


    < div className={styles.Apps} >


        <div className={styles.StatusTitles}>Apbo detailed analytics</div>

        <div className={styles.StatusBox} >
            <div className={styles.StatusBoxItemm}>
                {/* <span className={styles.StatusBoxItemmTitlee}>APBO Nft Sales Chart</span> */}
                <div id="chart" className={styles.chartt}></div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

Comment: I got this error if the #chart didn't actually exist ( document.querySelector('#chart') is empty).

Answer (score 1):

```js
var chartOrigin = document.querySelector('#chart');
if(chartOrigin) {
    var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector('#chart'), options);
    chart.render();
}
```

It happens when document.querySelector('#chart') doesn't exist.
If you want to prevent error, use follow code.